# How to debug this?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am getting this weird crash...in my java application and using native library through jni..But i am not able to debug it cause normally if java craches in native library it will generate crash report hs_errXXXX.log. In my application it does not generate that but simply crashes with following error message, So is there is any best way to debug?

[image]

Comment: Did you also check the temp dir used by Java or to explicitly specify the error log location via -XX:ErrorFile? - see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/felog-138657.html

Comment: yes i tried that but still does not generate error log.. If i some how able to see where it is crashing then i can solve this...as source is controlled by me

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources on how to debug JNI code on Windows:

- Using NetBeans - http://vilimpoc.org/research/debug-jni/
- Using Eclipse (with a bit of help from Visual Studio) http://thisisnotaprogrammersblog.blogspot.com.au/2008/04/debugging-jni-code-using-eclipse-and.html
- [Debugging the JNI code in VisualStudio 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286536/debugging-the-jni-code-in-visualstudio-2003) without using a Java IDE.

And there are others ...

---

This Answer is "Community Wiki".  Please feel free to update it!  (Or add updates as comments)

Comment: unfortunately i wont be able to user visual studio cause it's not c99 compliance...So tried with gdb but couldn't success as its happening in some particular  machine....which has windows xp in it..